# hammer.js - jQuery Mobile event-conflicts

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, hammer.js

Using hammer.js and hammer.jquery.js the tap event is called twice:

```
$('#button').hammer().on("tap press", function(e) {
    console.log('alert!°');
}
```

This is because JQM also defines events that hammer.js defines. But i just want to have the "tap" from hammer.js

I can't disable events on JQM-custom-builder because then i don't have any page transitions, etc.